# How to resolve "enter the password for credential storage" issue?

Tags: android, wifi, ssl-certificate, certificate-authority

So I am playing around with fiddler web proxy. I need to decrypt https traffic. So I am trying to put the fiddler root CA cert in my device trust store. But it keeps asking me `"Enter the password for credential storage"`. If i enter anything and click enter I see an `Toast` message saying

> Credential storage has been erased

and the password prompt comes again. This goes on in a loop. For the record I have selected `"Wifi"` as the Credential use instead of `"App n VPN"` (not sure of that matters).

[image]

Next wired thing that I noticed is that after each prompt the description changes for label

> The package contains

The value for it increases each time the password prompt is shown. For eg - 3 CA certificates, 4 CA certificates and so on...

[image]

As much as I want my device to accept this certificate I would appreciate if someone could explain the "credential storage" concept and the weird increment of CA certs text.

[Intercepting Android network calls using Fiddler Web Proxy](http://opensourceforgeeks.blogspot.in/2015/03/intercepting-android-network-calls.html)

Comment: check http://www.pocketables.com/2014/02/fix-credential-storage-roadblock-android.html n https://freestatedrivers.com/android-type-the-password-for-credential-storage/

Comment: @SubhalaxmiNayak The approach is 1st link worked. Found the same in android central forum too. Thanks.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I could now install the certificate. I had to disable pattern screen lock and try installing certificate again. This time it asked me to setup security - pin or password.

[image]

That I did and cert got installed. Got the solution from android central forum.

http://forums.androidcentral.com/google-nexus-7-tablet-2012/301151-credential-storage.html

I guess that thread is for VPN but same solution works for Wifi certs as well. Please do add if anyone has any additional info on this or workaround.

Comment: It didn't allow me to remove the pattern pin. So I changed it to a password pin and the install worked this time though it prompted me for a password.

Comment: I'm still stuck after trying all these things

Answer (score 0):

you must create a password to block/unblock smartPhone, Not PIN, maybe Patter, I try set a password and works fine

Comment: For a useful answer this reaction needs to be extended. Explain why this is an answer to the question.