# Always ask "enter the password for credential storage”?

Tags: android, ssl-certificate, wifi, certificate-authority

I've tried all the procedures I found on the internet.

https://www.pocketables.com/2014/02/fix-credential-storage-roadblock-android.html

https://freestatedrivers.com/android-type-the-password-for-credential-storage/

http://opensourceforgeeks.blogspot.com/2015/03/intercepting-android-network-calls.html

https://forums.androidcentral.com/google-nexus-7-tablet-2012/301151-credential-storage.html

Even here from the forum.

[How to resolve "enter the password for credential storage" issue?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29279486/how-to-resolve-enter-the-password-for-credential-storage-issue)

Always prompts me to enter the password in the CA installation for authentication on a wifi network with radius.

[enter the password image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OmCJzm.png)

Any other tip?